# Why are all my messages getting auto archived?

Tags: sms

I have One Plus 3 running OxygenOS (Android 6.0.1). Of late I am facing a weird issue. All my important incoming messages (SMS) are automatically moving to Archived section. Also I am getting no notification for them same. Only few crap SMSs which I don't care about land up in Inbox.

How to fix this? I am missing on important updates because of this. I am using the default Messenger app.

Comment: Does it change of you install a third party SMS app? If yes, it could point to OS issue

Comment: I uninstalled the updates on Messenger app, and then reinstalled the updates. Now it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Good. If that solves the problem, you can post that as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue got fixed for me. I went to Messenger app's App Info page. From options (top right corner three vertical dots) choose `Uninstall Updates`. My app already started working fine after this. However, it was again auto-updated to latest version and is still working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Open default sms app
Click on three dots icon on top right of the screen
Select Settings
Deselect or Disable the "Auto archive OTP's" option under Features.

Comment: Hi, is this the default SMS app on OnePlus 3 running OxygenOS Android 6.0.1? Otherwise, could you mention the name of the default SMS app, the device model, and the Android version since "the default SMS app" on other devices may have different features (and not this).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue wherein SMS (except few useless ones) were going in Archived folder. I went to Settings-Messenger- '3-dot at the top' and did "Uninstall Updates". This took the Messenger app back to factory version and voila, the OTP message from HDFC was right in the Inbox !!!